# Nexmo Inbound Message Parameters

Tags: php, vonage

I'm using Nexmo as SMS provider. I wanted to know if there is anyway to add parameters to the GET array that's returned in an inbound message.
I've tried modifying the callback url (for eg. https://xxxx.com/pqr?username=aaaa&pwd=bbbb), but that doesn't work.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an undocumented feature in Nexmo that can add additional parameters to the GET array. This needs to be requested to the Nexmo Help Desk. And, they will add it for all the numbers on your account. Hope this helps someone.